# postfix dkim=neutral reason="invalid (public key: missing p= tag)" outgoing email not received

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, dkim, opendkim

I use postfix to send outgoing emails ... a user does not receive sent posts ... when I sent same to my gmail account post does arrive in inbox ... yet below is what appears on Show Original

> Authentication-Results: example.com (amavisd-new); dkim=neutral (1024-bit key) reason="invalid (public key: missing p= tag)" header.d=example.com

here is my DNS domain TXT record for dkim

```
dig +short TXT   mail._domainkey.example.com. 
"v=DKIM1;"
"k=rsa;"
"p=MIGfMA0GCSqGblahblahblahDCBiQKBgQC55gymo9hvcdVpZIXhsO2Gn2hjJdcngKfkab7sDoYV6lvZYe/4euT+JbMk2PUMeWyGuJdkhv+iGzO8CMwjWO9PMOfMZGC8zd4ID3q7dP7QplV93j4i20tMk9fHTQYi0KFI8CB6sDhIhqKgEaJi6PL9DRQlahV00n6DqeWPSzJQNQIDAQAB;"
```

any ideas ?  Above format worked in the past just fine

I am sending email using [github.com:tomav/docker-mailserver](https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver)  which runs in a Ubuntu 14.04 container where I host it on AWS using route 53

```
/usr/sbin/opendkim -V       
opendkim: OpenDKIM Filter v2.9.1
    Compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
    SMFI_VERSION 0x1000001
    libmilter version 1.0.1
    Supported signing algorithms:
        rsa-sha1
        rsa-sha256
    Supported canonicalization algorithms:
        relaxed
        simple
    Active code options:
        QUERY_CACHE
        USE_DB
        USE_LDAP
        USE_LUA
        USE_ODBX
        USE_UNBOUND
        _FFR_ATPS
        _FFR_RBL
        _FFR_REPLACE_RULES
        _FFR_STATS
        _FFR_VBR
    libopendkim 2.9.1: atps query_cache



/usr/sbin/amavisd-new -V
amavisd-new-2.7.1 (20120429)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dig output, but if the above means 3 TXT records, and not one single record with 3 Strings, this is probably the problem. Only one TXT records per selector is allowed in DKIM.